# How do I set up CORS?

Tags: 8, symfony-services

Drupal 8 has RESTful web service in-built in core and since 8.2 we don't need [cors module](https://www.drupal.org/project/cors).

Now to use services we just enable and configure default.service.yml file as specified in [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2715637)

However, I was not able to configure this setup to allow web service access over another domain.

My current service.yml setup for cors is:

```
cors.config:
    enabled: true
    # Specify allowed headers, like 'x-allowed-header'.
    allowedHeaders: ['x-csrf-token,authorization,content-type,accept,origin,x-requested-with']
    # Specify allowed request methods, specify ['*'] to allow all possible ones.
    allowedMethods: ['POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT']
    # Configure requests allowed from specific origins.
    allowedOrigins: ['*']
    # Sets the Access-Control-Expose-Headers header.
    exposedHeaders: false
    # Sets the Access-Control-Max-Age header.
    maxAge: 1000
    # Sets the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header.
    supportsCredentials: false
```

I googled to find further detailed configuration on this but could not find one.

I am creating this for test development across two different domains.

Using pantheon dev environment for web services and localhost custom .dev domain for consuming those services.

Service access working fine using chrome CORS extension.

Comment: If you have already changed your site/default/services.yml as it said in previous answers, and It didn't work, make sure that CORS is enabled in your web server. For example, in Nginx you have to add/modified a location in your server block configurantion see [https://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html](https://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html)

Comment: services.yml should be under sites/default/ not in sites/. I wasted one hour because of this!!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I ran into this fairly recently on Pantheon, and hopefully this helps if you haven't already solved it.

```
cors.config:
    enabled: true
    # Specify allowed headers, like 'x-allowed-header'.
    allowedHeaders: ['x-csrf-token','authorization','content-type','accept','origin','x-requested-with', 'access-control-allow-origin','x-allowed-header','*']
    # Specify allowed request methods, specify ['*'] to allow all possible ones.
    allowedMethods: ['*']
    # Configure requests allowed from specific origins.
    allowedOrigins: ['http://localhost/','http://localhost:3000','http://localhost:3001','http://localhost:3002','*']
    # Sets the Access-Control-Expose-Headers header.
    exposedHeaders: false
    # Sets the Access-Control-Max-Age header.
    maxAge: false
    # Sets the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header.
    supportsCredentials: true
```

A few things to note...

Regarding the location of the file on Pantheon, please make sure your service.yml file is in /sites/default vs just /sites. I was wrongly under the impression it would work from both places. It will only work if in the /sites/default directory.

Notice the comma separated list of allowedHeaders each in their own set of quotes. I originally had a single string like you do in your example above, and it failed countless times before I caught the subtle difference. I'm fairly certain allowedMethods works the same way if you specifically want to list out your methods.

Please also note that while my code snippet will work well for development against a Pantheon sandbox you will likely want to lock things down a bit more prior to going into production. With Pantheon offering HTTPS you will also want to make sure to use it if you are going to be passing information around through headers. Hope this helps either you if you are still having issues or someone else that stumbled upon it down the road.

Comment: Why specify allowedOrigins and then also pass '*' ?

Comment: Simply to show both options. Please feel free to omit one or the other.

Comment: exposedHeaders should be false or an array, per https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2905848

Comment: If anyone's interested, I don't believe that the allowedOrigins field accepts regex.  I tried a use a regex pattern to whitelist multiple sub-domains, and drupal complained.  I had to use an explicit list of domains, comma-separated, like in this example.  I was hoping it would behave like the trusted-hosts setting in settings.php

Comment: @TonyStecca: asm89/stack-cors accepts regex patterns since version 1.2.0, via the allowedOriginsPatterns config parameter.
For anybody wanting to help make the 'new' parameter easy to discover, some feedback for https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3205688 would be appreciated.

Comment: To configure Nginx, add/modify `add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';` in your server config.

Comment: Bit late but I wanted to mention what made it work on my end. The defaults for "allowedHeaders" mentioned as a solution usually don't explicitly include `access-control-allow-origin`, such as the example in the original question. This is what is really needed. As soon as I added this and cleared cache: `access-control-allow-origin: http://localhost:3000` appears in my response headers and it's good to go. (Obviously the request is coming from localhost:3000 in my case, no wildcards needed)

Comment: How to add CORS on Pantheon for "direct" files not just for pages that "generated via Drupal"?

Answer (score 14):

Find:
.../sites/default/default.services.yml

Make a copy and rename the copy to:

.../sites/default/services.yml

Find this part of the code:
cors.config:
enabled: false

and replace with the following -
cors.config:
enabled: true

Clear the cache.

Comment: I supposed tried everything till saw your answer, thanks for showing the most important point which is CLEARING THE CACHE (REBUILD CACHE)  :D

Answer (score 5):

The following setting working for me.

```
cors.config:
  enabled: true
  # Specify allowed headers, like 'x-allowed-header'.
  allowedHeaders: ['x-csrf-token','authorization','content-type','accept','origin','x-requested-with']
  # Specify allowed request methods, specify ['*'] to allow all possible ones.
  allowedMethods: ['*']
  # Configure requests allowed from specific origins.
  allowedOrigins: ['*']
  # Sets the Access-Control-Expose-Headers header.
  exposedHeaders: false
  # Sets the Access-Control-Max-Age header.
  maxAge: false
  # Sets the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header.
  supportsCredentials: false
```

Answer (score 1):

exposedHeaders: true is not valid and will cause
Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in Asm89\Stack\CorsService->addActualRequestHeaders() (line 94 of /vendor/asm89/stack-cors/src/Asm89/Stack/CorsService.php) #0 /web/core/includes/bootstrap.inc(584)
It needs to be either false or an array with allowed headers to expose
see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers

Answer (score 0):

Nothing of above worked for me.
Finally I followed this [article](https://www.solutionspirit.com/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-drupal-8-x-rest-apis/) and installed this contrib module: https://www.drupal.org/project/advanced_cors.

I cleared cache et voilà, I could get it working.