# jsonapi Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response in vue

Tags: 8

I got the data with postman in json:api at drupal.
[image]
 But I has error of CORB in  Vue-resource.get() with code blew：

```
 data(){
    return{
        cyclePic:[],
        rootUrl:this.$http.options.root,
        header:{headers:{Accept:'application/vnd.api+json',
            'Content-type':'application/vnd.api+json',
            Authorization:"Basic dG1wQWRtaW46VG1wQDEyMyM0NTY="}                
            }                     
    }
},
created(){
    this.getCycleList()
},
methods:{
    getCycleList(){

        this.$http.get('jsonapi/node/banner?include=field_image',this.header).then(result=>{
            console.log(result)

            if(result.ok && result.status===200){
                this.cyclePic=result.body.included
                console.log(this.cyclePic)
            }else{
                Toast('Fail')
            }

        })
    }
```

what i miss some thing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up your Cors settings 
Look at your services.yml file then read ...

[How do I set up CORS?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/245903/how-do-i-set-up-cors)

Comment: How to doing ? Drupal 8 restrict the Cors module .Or you can recommend the CORS module for me.thanks.

Comment: read the link aka https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/245903/how-do-i-set-up-cors
above then edit your "sites/default/default.services.yml" file !